# Add fixed string to the end of route parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using React Router v6.4.1 and would like to have a consistent ending to a set of dynamic routes.

For instance, I would like my product detail routes to ends with "-product".

Say I have a path like "/shaver-900-product". This should trigger my `ProductDetails` component which could then use "shaver-900" to get the product details from my API.

I've tried defining the path using the following, but I cannot get this working:

```
<Route path=":productSlug-product" element={<ProductDetails />} />
```

If the product slug in the API/Database changes to have "-product", then this would work:

```
<Route path=":productSlug" element={<ProductDetails />} />
```

However, I would prefer to not change the database and only make the changes to how the routes are matched.

Comment: Sorry, after reading, and rereading, your question it's unclear to me if you even need to match route paths with a `"-product"` suffix since it sounds like your data *doesn't* have ids ending with `"-product"`. Where is this suffix coming from?

Comment: My attempt at improving SEO

Comment: I see. So if I'm understanding correctly, the `"-product"` suffix exists only from *some* link (*internal or external*) to your app where this route would be matched and then stripped out to get the actual product id, is this correct? If so, then I think my answer below stands as-is. If not then please try to fill in the gaps so the use case is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

`react-router-dom@6` route paths no longer handle any sort of regex patterns for path matching, the path parameters are effectively all or nothing. Use the  `productSlug` param and handle the string manipulation in the matched routed component.

```
<Route path=":productSlug" element={<ProductDetails />} />
```

Path is `"/shaver-900-product"`.

```
const ProductDetails = () => {
  const { productSlug } = useLocation();

  ... logic to extract "shaver-900" from productSlug ...

  ...
};
```